# Nginx + Passenger Enterprise: Node Not Found

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I am running multiple Ruby apps with Nginx and Passenger Enterprise, and everythings running fine. I tried to run a Node.js app and I am getting this error:

```
App 2243 output: /bin/sh: 1: exec: 
App 2243 output: node: not found
App 2243 output:
```

I tried "node -v" with the following users: root, nginx user, and app.js owne, and node was found on all of them.

These are my nginx.conf settings:

```
server {
            listen  80;
            server_name     mysite.com;
            root    myapp_root/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
            passenger_app_type node;
            passenger_startup_file app.js;
  }
```

Why is node not found by nginx + passenger?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your server block:

```
passenger_nodejs path/to/node;
```